# Python Lambda function to perform some operation on different CSV files depending on file names

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have to open and perform some logic on three different CSV files which I am uploading into S3.

Location: my-bucket/config/

File names: Employee.csv, Organisation.csv, Expenses.csv

I am trying to right a lambda function using python so that when any of these files is uploaded my lambda function gets triggered and then by the name of the file uploaded I should be able to identify the logic which has to be written. The pseudocode looks something like:

1. If Employee.csv is uploaded in S3 do something...
2. If Organisation.csv is uploaded in S3 do something...
3. If Expenses.csv is uploaded in S3 do something...

All I need to know is how to right the 'if' condition to match the file names from S3 bucket.
Also, I have configured the trigger for the lambda function on any file which is uploaded in S3. Is there any way that I can configure S3 bucket to only trigger my lambda function only when these three files are uploaded?

Comment: Re: conditional trigger, no. But you can always check the file name in your lambda and do nothing if it's not a file you're interested in. As to the rest, please show your current code, because right now it sounds like "write this code for me".

Comment: all I need to know is the if condition which I need to put check the file names from S3 bucket

Comment: I don't know python so can't help, but the lambda will receive an event in a particular structure (documented in AWS docs), the file name will be accessible in there. So using pseudo code in a more javascript flavour: `var fileName = event.Records[0].attributes.key; if (!expectedFileNames.contains(fileName)) { return; } // now you know you're dealing with one of your desired files`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by this code:

def lambda_handler(event, context)

```
if event:
    file_object=event["Records"][0]
    file_name=str(file_object['s3']['object']['key'])
    print(file_name)

    if(file_name == key):
        #To do logic
```